# Set default theme colors for widgets?

Tags: android, colors, android-widget, themes, android-theme

Widget colors differ between devices: the Galaxy Tab, for instance, uses a
bluish/teal color for highlighted tabs and for preference sub-text,
whereas the Dell Streak uses a dark gray.

Is it possible to set the default theme colors used by widgets? Or where are these colors derived from?