# How do I change the theme of one particular View in android?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I want to use the Switch widget in my Android app, but with the theme of Samsung devices they don't allow the text on the switches to be changed. It just shows a lame "I" or a "O" on the switch regardless of what you change the on/off text to.

I want to keep my application's theme to Device Default, but how do I switch the theme of my "Switch" widget to regular Holo theme?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875104/set-default-theme-colors-for-widgets

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the backports of Switch like https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport

This will give you complete control over the look of Switch.